# ¿Cómo saber si la fecha esta dentro del rango de días de trabajo o descanso?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Como puedo saber si las fechas que obtengo, están dentro de los días de trabajo o días de descanso.

```
Declare @NumOperador int, @FechaDesde datetime, @FechaHasta datetime, @cveJornada int
set @FechaDesde='2017-07-01 00:00:00.000'
set @FechaHasta='2017-07-31 00:00:00.000'
set @NumOperador=900056
set @cveJornada=4

Select distinct cc.NumOperador,
  CONVERT(DATE,X.Fecha) Fecha
from CopCalendario CC
INNER JOIN trfDespacho D on D.numOperador=cc.NumOperador
INNER JOIN trkJornada J on j.cveJornada=cc.TipoJornada
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
                      (D.FechaSalida),
                      (D.FechaLlegada)
                 ) x(Fecha)
where (CC.NumOperador= @NumOperador or @NumOperador=0)
AND D.FechaSalida BETWEEN @FechaDesde AND (@FechaHasta+1) 
and D.FechaSalida is not null and D.FechaLlegada is not null
```

[image: Resultado]

Si la Jornada que tiene el empleado es 4x2 (Trabaja 4 días y descansa 2) y su Jornada inicial es el 3 de Julio.

Los días de trabajo y los dias de descanso estan definidos en la tabla de trkJornada:

[image: Tabla trkJornada]

En la Tabla de Copcalendario estan los números de empleado con su Tipo de Jornada y el día de inicio de Jornada:

[image: Tabla CopCalendario]

en la Tabla de trfDespacho es en donde estan registradas las fechas, si hay registro de fecha es asitencia si no hay Fecha Registrada es falta.

Comment: Por favor aclara en donde estan definidos los dias de trabajo y los dias de descanso, no es posible saberlo con la informacion que publicaste. Tal vez si colocas las estructuras de las tablas que hacen parte de la consulta sea mas fácil entenderlo.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario @Mauricio, he agregado más información en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea es esta, tal vez toque ajustarle los valores, pero en terminus generals deberia funcionar, asi podemos calcular los ciclos de dias total :

Para el caso 4x2 :

Si el DateDiff da 12 entonces el modulo a 6 dara 0 lo que nos dice que es un dia laboral

Si el DateDiff da 17 el modulo a 6 dara 5 por lo que es mayor que el numero de  dias laborales, por lo tanto debe ser dia de Descanso.

Espero haber sido claro, pienso que este codigo es un buen punto de inicio, aunque como te dije, tal vez debas hacerle algun ajuste.

```
Select distinct cc.NumOperador,
  CONVERT(DATE,X.Fecha) Fecha,
  case 
    when (DateDiff(day, cc.jornada_ini, CONVERT(DATE,X.Fecha)) % j.DiasTotal)<j.DiasLabores
    then 'Dia Labor' else 'Dia Descanso' end as tipoDia
from CopCalendario CC
INNER JOIN trfDespacho D on D.numOperador=cc.NumOperador
INNER JOIN trkJornada J on j.cveJornada=cc.TipoJornada
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
                  (D.FechaSalida),
                  (D.FechaLlegada)
             ) x(Fecha)
where (CC.NumOperador= @NumOperador or @NumOperador=0)
AND D.FechaSalida BETWEEN @FechaDesde AND (@FechaHasta+1) 
and D.FechaSalida is not null and D.FechaLlegada is not null
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Mauricio realice pruebas con diferentes Jornada y no modifique nada, me ha sido de mucha utilidad.Saludos.